# add existing unversioned directory as git submodule in place (while avoiding moving and copying as much as possible)

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to convert a unversioned subdirectory of a git project clone into a submodule.
The straightforward way would be to move it out, create a project and re-add this project as a submodule.
Is there a way to do this in place, e.g. avoid moving, copying locally and transferring most of the data again from the server?

Example:

I have a git project named "test" cloned to a directory "test", where the only versioned file is readme.md. Hoewver, there's a huge subdirectory testsm which i'd like to create a git project "testsm" for and then add it as a submodule in the folder "test/testsm".

```
/test
/readme.md (versioned)
/testsm/* (yet unversioned)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an existing git repository with `git submodule add`.

In your case, you first need to create a new git repo with `git init` in the `testsm` directory. You will also need to create at least one commit.

You will then have this structure:

```
base
`- .git
`- readme.md
`- testsm
   `- .git
   `- other files...
```

Once you are there, you can add the submodule with:

```sh
git submodule add ./testsm
git commit # To actually commit the changes
```

*The following steps are optional.*

If you need to set an upstream url, you can use the `git submodule set-url` command to set the submodule URL to what you want.

You can also move the `testsm/.git` repository to the parent `.git` repository with `git submodule absorbgitdirs`.